# git merge --allow-unrelated-histories process stuck

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-merge

Following is the commands I run to merge repo projectA to a new-created empty repo projectB.

projectA is a repo migrated from SVN using "git svn clone', and it contains Git Large File Storage objects.

run command "git merge --allow-unrelated-histories projectA/master" is stuck and I waited about a hour and there was no status update or error message, I gave up and forcefully closed the command prompt.

Is there any way to know what happened and prevent the merge process stuck, thanks.

```
cd C:\GitHub\projectA 

Python c:\Work\git-filter-repo --to-subdirectory-filter projectA 

cd C:\GitHub\projectB 

git remote add projectA  C:\Work\GitHub\projectA 

git fetch projectA  --tags

git merge --allow-unrelated-histories projectA/master //stuck,did not output anything on command prompt 

git remote remove projectA
```

Comment: Isn't that your local machine and not GitHub Actions runner? It seems to be related to `git` and not `github-actions` tag.

Comment: debugging aside, can you describe what you expect to do with this merge action ? If the files on disk are completely separate, and the histories are completely unrelated, there are other ways to create some commit to join the histories.

Comment: thanks, @LeGEC, what I expect to do is same as this question and I'm doing this on Win 10: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories,  what is the other ways you mentioned.

Comment: is `ProjectB` 100% empty ? If you want to push history from `A` to `B`, you can simply push `projectA/master` to `B`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few environment variables that will give you some insight on what is happening under the hood :

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging

try setting `GIT_TRACE=1` or `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1`.

You can also look into generic debugging tools : on linux I would suggest `strace` or `perf`, for Windows I will let other users advise you.